# Is there a difference between a 'mini-DisplayPort to HDMI cable' and a 'mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort' cable for a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, 4k

I just bought a 4k monitor (AOC u2777pqu) for my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inch, Early 2015). The shop advised a mini-DisplayPort to HDMI cable, which gives me 4k resolution but when I tried it only provided a refresh rate of 30Hz.

The Apple support guide ( https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT206587 ) suggests that the Thunderbolt cable will allow this model to run 4k at 60Hz.

My question whether getting a 'pure DisplayPort' ( mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable - 4k certified) provide the 60Hz at 4k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially, your model MacBook Pro will support up to 3840 by 2160 pixels at 30Hz or 4096 by 2160 pixels at 24Hz if using a HDMI connection, which explains your experience of 30Hz with your mini-DisplayPort to HDMI cable.

Your model MacBook Pro also supports up to 3840 by 2160 pixels at 60Hz using a Thunderbolt connection. Since your display supports both a 60Hz refresh rate and a DisplayPort connection, then using a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable of sufficient quality *should* achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, I concur that according to the documentation a 'pure DP' cable should achieve this. I was looking for confirmation that using a 'mini-dp to hdmi' would result in a refresh rate of 30hz, and a 'mini-dp to dp' cable would allow a refresh rate of 60hz.

Comment: I noticed that this related question, although using different hardware, strongly suggests @Monomeeth 's answer is correct: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201720/macbook-pro-2015-15-with-asus-pb279q-4k-60hz?rq=1

Comment: I purchased a Mini-DP to DP (1.2) cable, and it is really a great picture at 60hz. Do not buy a mini-DP to HDMI adapter for 4k monitors!

Comment: That's great! And thanks for reporting back to share your experience! :)